# Firebase Python Function called from Firebase Hosted App

Tags: javascript, python, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I would like to call a firebase function written in Python from my firebase hosted app. I've followed the documentation here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#call_the_function) for writing the calling part of the function in my JS, and the documentation here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd) for how to call the app.

A main point I think I've seen from the documentation and writing my functions:

1. If you want to call the function with a simple https request (using fetch or similar), then the Python firebase function uses the `@https_fn.on_request()` decorator. If you want to call it using the firebase app functions call, you use the `@https_fn.on_call()` decorator. From what I've seen, `on_request` will work (without auth), but `on_call` never works (despite being advertised as native Firebase, passing auth automagically).

I've got a minimal sample code for the `on_call` decorator below. I deployed the function via the google cloud console directly (I'm also having errors deploying code from the firebase CLI). The entrypoint on google cloud console is spec'd as `say_hello`, and if I run the code with the commented `on_request` decorator I can call it successfully from an http request.

Python Firebase Function [function name: `function-hw`]:

```py
import functions_framework
# [START v2imports]
# Dependencies for callable functions.
from firebase_functions import https_fn, options

# Dependencies for writing to Realtime Database.
from firebase_admin import db, initialize_app, auth
# [END v2imports]

from datetime import datetime

#@https_fn.on_request(
@https_fn.on_call(
    cors=options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins=[r"https://jr\.mysite\.app$"],
        cors_methods=["get", "post"],
    )
)
def say_hello(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    print(req.__dict__)
    return {
        "Hello": "World!",
        "Time": "CORS!",
        "Now": datetime.now()
    }
```

JS Calling code:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-functions.js";


// Correct info is in my actual app
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "..."
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp);
var callFunction = httpsCallable('function-hw');
callFunction()
  .then(function(result) {
    // Handle success
    console.log(result.data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });


async function requestFunction() {
  const fcnUrl = "url for firebase function with on_request decorator";
  const response = await fetch(fcnUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
requestFunction()
```

When I load my site, I expect it to call the function, but I get:

```
service.ts:185 Uncaught TypeError: e._url is not a function
at call (service.ts:185:59)
at service.ts:215:3
at index.js:37:1  // -> This is the `callFunction()` line in my Javascript
```

And the 'on_request' function executes as expected, returning JSON in the console:

```
{Hello: 'World!', Now: 'Thu, 21 Mar 2024 15:01:07 GMT', Time: 'CORS!'}
```

This would work for me, except once I go to add auth headers it falls over.

So my questions:

1. Am I doing something incorrect with the 'on_call' Firebase function?
2. Is there a way I can implement auth with 'on_request'? I've tried the 'bearer ${token}' routine already with no success.

Comment: From what I can see, your function is called `say_hello`, not `function-hw`.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, the function name is 'say_hello', but from what I can tell Google refers to them by their cloud-console names, not the Python function name. I'll try say_hello to see if that works and report back.

Comment: The example in the documentation (addmessage) you linked to suggests otherwise.

Comment: Hi Doug, same result. This makes sense, because I can have multiple cloud functions with the same name for the entry point (say_hello), but the cloud function is called differently. I am currently deploying my firebase functions directly from console.cloud.google.com, since the Firebase CLI doesn't work for deploying the Python functions. Perhaps this is where the error is coming from, but if so, I'm surprised that the 'fetch' function works.

Comment: Also, from what I can tell you specify the function name as shown here with Google Cloud CLI, again, maybe it needs to be Firebase CLI to make it work, but I haven't been able to get that to work with Python. Have you been able to get it to work with Python, or only JS?

`gcloud functions deploy [Function-name-in-gcloud] --gen2 --runtime=python311 --region=us-central1 --source=. --entry-point=[Python function name] --trigger-http`

Comment: I wouldn't expect a Firebase callable function to work when deployed from the cloud console, nor from gcloud.  Callables are a firebase thing and not understood by GCP natively.  You need to use the Firebase CLI for that exactly as described in the documentation.  If the Firebase CLI doesn't work, then you should submit a bug report for that.

Comment: I've tried `firebase deploy --only functions` with no luck. I'm surprised that it wouldn't work from google cloud with the correct Python libraries as dependencies in my requirements.txt 

As far as a bug report, this is pretty much the most basic functionality in using Python with Firebase, I would assume Google would have some kind of quality checks on this. I think its more likely I'm doing something wrong than Google just didn't test the most basic functionality. I've seen you on other questions, you seem to be the expert for Firebase on SO, have you ever got it working with Python?

Comment: I've never tried.  I suggest filing a bug report.